# Gmail: elements bigger than the size defined in inline css styles

Tags: html, css, gmail, html-email

So I'm coding html of an newsletter and i'm using the inline styles because of restrictions, so my "table layout" is broken because have  elements with size bigger than the defined.
I realize that an  element with 170px of height defined, and inside them have an  tag with 170px of height defined, so why using inspect i can see that this  have 172px, i think Gmail is ignoring something.

I make a gif to show this in inspector: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnXEz.gif

My JSfiddle with my html: http://jsfiddle.net/wtkd/ygfn6qka/
**(the boxes with images of mario shows where layout breaks)**
If you don't want to see in JSfiddle:

```
  <table width="700" align="center" style="background-image: url('http://www.image.test.com/images/bg.jpg'); background-color: #ededed; background-position: center top; background-repeat: no-repeat; margin:0;padding:0;padding: 0; width: 700px; margin: 0 auto;">
<tr width="600" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;">
  <td style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;">
    <table width="600" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=
    "border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;">
      <thead width="600" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;">
        <tr width="600"height="150" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;">
          <th width="600" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;">
            <img src="http://www.image.test.com/images/header.png" width="600" height="151">
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr height="104">
          <th style="height:104px; border-bottom: 5px #ededed solid;">
            <img src="http://www.image.test.com/images/update.png" width="600" height="104">
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody width="600">
        <tr height="170">
          <th height="170">
            <a style="height:170px;" href="http://www.test.com/motorola-droid-turbo/65466-moto-maxx-chega-oficialmente-brasil-preco-r-xxxx.htm" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.image.test.com/images/moto-maxx.png" width="600" height="170"></a>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr height="180">
          <th height="170">
            <a style="height:170px;" href="http://www.test.com/jogos/65442-explosivo-trailer-gameplay-gta-v-confirma-modo-primeira-pessoa.htm" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.image.test.com/images/gta-v.png" width="600" height="170"></a>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <table width="600" height="340" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=
            "border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;">
            <tr>
              <th height="170" style="height: 170px; width: 200px;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;">
                <a style="height: 170px; width: 200px;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;" href="http://www.test.com/moto-x/65400-analise-review-smartphone-motorola-novo-moto-x-2014.htm" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.image.test.com/images/moto-x.png" width="200" height="170"></a>
              </th>
              <th height="170" style="height: 170px; width: 200px;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;">
                <a style="height: 170px; width: 200px;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;" href="http://www.test.com/iphone-6/64640-analise-apple-iphone-6-review.htm" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.image.test.com/images/iphone.png" width="200" height="170"></a>
              </th>
              <th rowspan="2" height="340" style="width: 200px; height: 340px;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;">
                <a style="width: 200px; height: 340px;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;" href="http://www.test.com/jogos/65339-personagens-super-mario-viram-brindes-mcdonalds-brasileiro.htm" target="_blank"><img src="http://img.elo7.com.br/product/original/62C89A/painel-mario-bros.jpg" width="200" height="340"></a>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr width="400" height="170">
              <th height="170" colspan="2" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;">
                <a style="width:400px;height:170px;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;" href="http://www.test.com/celular/65283-dinossauros-9-celulares-marcaram-epoca.htm" target="_blank"><img src="http://cdn.bgr.com/2013/11/super-mario-3d-world.jpg" width="400" height="170"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <table width="700" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=
              "border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;background:#ededed;">
            <tr align="center" height="170" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;">
              <th height="170">
                <a href="http://www.test.com/cinema/65416-30-filmes-2015-voce-querer-ver-cinemas-estreias-lancamentos.htm" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.image.test.com/images/filmes.png" width="600" height="170"></a>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr height="180" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;">
              <td colspan="2" style="width:400px;height:170px;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;">
                <img src="http://www.image.test.com/images/grupo-nzn.jpg" width="600" height="180">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Someone can help about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `display:block;` inline on all your `img` tags.

Answer (score 1):

It's something related to the way `<a>` are displayed. Changing their `display` property to `block` (individually, or globally with a style, and I'm curious to know why you are not allowed to use it) did the trick: [running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ygfn6qka/1/)

```
<style>
    a {
        display : block;        
    }
</style>
```

Comment: In jsFiddle it works, but in Gmail doesn't work sadly,
Gmail don't accept <style> tags, i put this display block in all of <a> elements inline but don't fix, you have any other idea?

Comment: it worked for me with inline style too... are you sure you've putted it in all <a> ?